# ADF RichTextEditor autosubmit doesn't work in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, events, onchange, rich-text-editor

I'm facing a problem when using the RichTextEditor with autosubmit="true" in JDev 12c. The component is added programmatically on a form.

In Firefox the autosubmit fires correctly for any  kind of action (e.g.: typing, changing text style, etc)

On the other side in Chrome, not every action fires the autosubmit. For example, typing some text would fire the autosubmit, but then selecting the text and changing the color or the font size for example, doesn't fire a value change event / autosubmit.

Has anyone else encountered this type of behavior before?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using Windows 10?

Comment: @DeviKiran Yes, I am. But I can try on Windows 8 if you think this is the problem.

Comment: Please try on WIN7 Machine...there are know issues for WIN10 and chrome combination for ADF input components

Comment: @DeviKiran Firstly, thank you for your answer. I have just tried on WIN7 and same result occurred, in Firefox everything works properly, but in Chrome doesn't :(

Comment: hmm weird..we are also facing issues while using adf with google chrome...we have raised an service ticket with ADF development team regarding this ...un fortunately we dont have update about this issue from past decemebr 2016 :-(

Comment: I'm not going to wait until they will find a solution to this :)) I found a workaround with a plain textarea to which I applied some js & css. Thanks a lot for quick response !

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as well, `RichTextEditor`'s text is very difficult to erase the content or reset programatically too,
I advise to use other text tools like the very known `RichTextArea`:

```
// Create a rich text area
final RichTextArea rtArea = new RichTextArea();
rtArea .setCaption("My Rich Text Area");

// Set initial content as HTML
rtArea .setValue("<h1>Hello</h1>\n" +
                 "<p>This rich text area contains some text.</p>");
```

Then you could resize it to the size of the `RichTextEditor` and give it the same visual color by some tricks through `js` and `css` as usual.